# Make onRequestPermissionsResult common for all activities android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to give marshmallow support by implementing the new permission model in my android app.
But if I need to check for any permission at multiple places in my application, I need to put this method onRequestPermissionsResult in each activity.

Is there any way by which we can make this method common and which will be called whenever any permission get requested from any activity, so that we do not have to write this method in each activity.

Thanks a lot for help in advanced.

Comment: You can look on www.androidxref.com for similar functionality.  I believe there are a few packages in AOSP that do this.